# ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found in SSRS session

Tags: asp.net, redis

I have an SSRS session state issue with legacy asp.net application. The session gets expires while loading SSRS reports.

The same session works in the application but if I ran the SSRS reports after some time/few reports session gives message as ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found.

Here we have used Redis session, since we have used load balancer and to get the session state if the request goes depend upon load balancer.

For session I have used below settings in Web.Config

**sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionStateProvider">
providers -
add name="RedisSessionStateProvider" type="RedisProvider.SessionProvider.CustomRedisSessionProvider" />**

Also, I tried with enableSessionState to false in Web.Config - pages sestion and set enablingSessionState to true at page level, but still the session not works in SSRS reports.

Kindly help me, how to fix the issue so that I will get the persistent session in SSRS reports?

Thanks.